# Mapbox waypoint arrival event in android

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I am using mapbox library for turn by turn navigation. In my application I need to perform some action when user reach to particular waypoints(stop-point). In IOS, there is **didArriveAt** method which call when reach to particular waypoint. I have search a lot but not found method like that in android. I found **onArrival** method but It's not call at waypoint arrive. Is there any way to know to reach that waypoint?

Comment: Have you tried using Custom Milestones to listen for events: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/milestones/#custom-milestones ?